# SQL: Removing Duplicate records - Albeit different kind

Tags: sql, oracle, duplicate-data, duplicates

Consider the following table:

```
TAB6
         A          B C
---------- ---------- -
         1          2 A
         2          1 A
         2          3 C
         3          4 D
```

I consider, the records {1,2, A} and {2, 1, A} as duplicate. I need to select and produce the below record set:

```
         A          B C                      A          B C
---------- ---------- -             ---------- ---------- -
         1          2 A         or           2          1 A
         2          3 C                      2          3 C
         3          4 D                      3          4 D
```

I tried the below queries. But to no avail.

```
select t1.*
from t6 t1
, t6 t2
where t1.a <> t2.b
and t1.b <> t2.a
and t1.rowid <> t2.rowid
/

         A          B C
---------- ---------- -
         1          2 A
         2          1 A
         2          1 A
         2          3 C
         3          4 D
         3          4 D

6 rows selected.
```

Or even this:

```
 select *
 from t6 t1
 where exists (select * from t6 t2 where t1.a <> t2.b and t1.b <> t2.a)
/
         A          B C
---------- ---------- -
         1          2 A
         2          1 A
         2          3 C
         3          4 D
```

Both did not work.

The database would be Oracle 10g. Looking  for a pure SQL solution. Every help is appreciated.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Please expand on this.

Comment: I need a SQL to produce the record set {1, 2, A}, {2, 3, C} and {3, 4, D}. For me {1, 2, A} and {2, 1, A} are duplicate records and the result set should have only one tuple (either {1, 2, A} or {2, 1, A}, but not both)

Comment: Just to be clear, by "remove" you mean *filter from result set* rather than *delete*.

Comment: @APC, you are right. Removing means, filtering in the result set. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use GREATEST() and LEAST() functions to identify the common values across multiple columns.  Then use DISTINCT to winnow out the duplicates.

```
select distinct least(a, b) as a
       , greatest(a, b) as b
       , c
from t6
```

This gives you the precise record set you asked for.  But things will get more complicated if you need to include other columns from T6.

---

> "But I was wondering if this will work for VARCHAR2 fields also?"

Yes but it will use ASCII values to determine order, which is not always what you might expect (or desire).

> "Also, my table T6 might have tens of thousand of records."

That really isn't a lot of data in today's terms.  The DISTINCT will cause a sort, which should be able to fit in memory unless `A` and `B` are really long VARCHAR2 columns - but probably even then.

If this is a query you're going to want to run a lot then you can build a function-based index to satisfy it:

```
create index t6_fbi on t6(least(a, b)
                           , greatest(a, b)
                           , c )
/
```

But I would really only bother if you have a genuine performance issue with the query.

Comment: Thanks @APC, I could not check this now. But I was wondering if this will work for VARCHAR2 fields also? Also, my table T6 might have tens of thousand of records.. I appreciate your response, but still Stackoverflow doesn't allow me to up vote you yet. :(

Answer (score 0):

If the order of columns A and B do not matter and always contain an integer, how about:

```
select distinct
  least(a, b) as a,
  greatest(a, b) as b,
  c
from
  t6
```