# sql find uniq row exclude different duplicate row

Tags: sql, row, unique, distinct-values

I have a table with:

```
id  field_id    todelete
1   x001        0
2   x001        1
3   x001        0
4   x002        1
5   x003        0
6   x003        1
7   x004        0
8   x005        0
```

From this I need `id 4`, it has `todelete = 1` and its unique in `field_id`. 
My current solution:

```
array = SELECT field_id WHERE todelete = 1
```

and from that array

```
SELECT field_id WHERE field_id = array[x] HAVING COUNT(field_id) = 1
```

Seems to be the wrong solution. Can I have this in SQL only way? Thanks

Comment: I believe this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/q/8829975/6495084

Comment: nope, I think it should look like
select field_id where todelete = 1 having count(field_id) = 1

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2? Firebird?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were on the good path. There is certainly other solutions but those are 2 that work as you want :

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23a6dd/9)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`id` int, `field_id` varchar(4), `todelete` int)
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`id`, `field_id`, `todelete`)
VALUES
    (1, 'x001', 0),
    (2, 'x001', 1),
    (3, 'x001', 0),
    (4, 'x002', 1),
    (5, 'x003', 0),
    (6, 'x003', 1),
    (7, 'x004', 0),
    (8, 'x005', 0)
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Table1
WHERE field_id in 
    (SELECT field_id
     FROM Table1
     WHERE todelete = 1)
GROUP BY field_id
HAVING count(*)=1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23a6dd/9/0)**:

```
| id |
|----|
|  4 |
```

**Query 2**:

```
SELECT id 
FROM Table1
WHERE todelete = 1
AND field_id in 
    (SELECT field_id
     FROM Table1
     GROUP BY field_id
     HAVING count(*)=1)
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/23a6dd/9/1)**:

```
| id |
|----|
|  4 |
```

Comment: Second example is exactly what I need. Thank you